# Benefits/Drawbacks of storing data in data structures, rather than embedding them in if/switch statements

Tags: arrays, assembly, compiler-construction, switch-statement, compiler-optimization

For Example, suppose I wanted to enumerate a list of strings { "ALPHA", "BETA", "GAMMA", "OMEGA" }. Two ways I can think of doing this:

```
--- Method 1 ---
string getType(int a)
{
   switch(a)
   {
      case 0: return "ALPHA"; 
      case 1: return "BETA";
      case 2: return "GAMMA";
      case 3: return "OMEGA";
   }
}
```

Or I could create an array of strings and use it to return the corresponding string element:

```
--- Method 2 ---
string data[] = { "ALPHA", "BETA", "GAMMA", "OMEGA" };
string getType(int a)
{
     return data[a];
}
```

(Assuming for a very large data set) How does the compiler deal with these two methods? What does the final assembly code look like? Is one method faster at retrieving elements than the other? Does one take more space in memory? Or do they get translated to the same machine code?

My best guess would be that method 2 works faster but also takes up more space in memory, as it needs the space for the array; whereas method 1 takes more time every time getType(..) is called but requires less memory as the variables are only stored in the assembly commands. But I still don't know how C++ or other language compilers would deal with the code, could produce something completely different.

Comment: You could probably answer some of these questions by just compiling and taking a look at the result...

Comment: Indeed, why so many people are unable to stop guessing and start looking?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the array.  It's clearly more efficient for large numbers of strings, and for small numbers of strings, the overhead of using an array over a switch statement is trivial anyway.  The benefit of you learning not to do crazy things is worth the extra overhead. :-)

If you really wanted to analyze the difference, I think you'd find that it can depend on the resources of the machine you are running it on anyway, since one approach is clearly more memory intensive and the other more CPU.